# Create a Angular/React Wrapper for R shiny (Single SPA)

Tags: r, reactjs, angular, shiny, single-page-application

I have created a R shiny application and having some other applications which are created using Angular for frontend. Now I want to embed these applications into a Single Page Application.

I have embeded all the application which was created using angular as a Single Page App. For that I used the main.js and index.html files there. But in shiny, as there only be ui.R and server.R files, I could not able to do that.

Using iframes, we can embed our shiny application in other websites. But due to some constraints, this method could not be able to use.

Is there a way, where we can write an angular/react wrapper which serves our shiny application?

Please share your suggestions/ways which can i use to achieve this Single SPA concept with shiny application.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.